# Problems with Ctrl+J

Tags: rigging

I'm merging two different rig files (head / body) and those have different types of armature either. I don't know if the difference of bone type is causing this but..

Head bone:
[image: head bone]

Body bone:
[image: body bone]

When I click the head bone first and then the body bone and join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, the head bone disappears and the head becomes a lot bigger:
[image: when i click head bone first and then body bone ctrl J head bone disappears and head becomes a lot bigger]

When I click the body bone first and then join the head bone, some of the body bones rearrange strangely and cannot be moved:
[image: when i click body bone first and then head bone ctrl J some of the body bones rearranged strangely and cannot be moved]

[image] edittingone

[image] forbody

[image] forhead

Comment: Using Ctrl+J, the resulting object will get the modifiers of the active object (last selected object). And an armature is a modifier. You should merge armatures first (if there is no name conflicts between their bones) then merge the meshes (do that at coherent object loc/rot/scales).

Comment: umm.. i can't understand what you are saying? you mean remove the armature modifier and then merge them then? (I tried to merged bones first before you told me

Comment: Ctrl+J will keep only one modifier, so one armature. If you join the armatures (before joining the meshes) that should work. But you need to check that rotations and scales of your meshes are ok (are the same or are applied).

Comment: actually joining armatures doesn't work Can you help me out with the blend file if you don't mind? (by mediafire or dropbox)

Comment: yes I can give it a look. Normally you should use this link here to upload the file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: oh, i uploaded it

Comment: head and body is from different file and the above panel is related to the orginal head rig // you need to be in pose mode to move body

Comment: This is a scale problem between the 2 armatures. But I don't know how to solve it for now.

Comment: yeah.. it's a big problem but thanks for your help XD

Comment: Don't you have some original unscaled armatures?

Comment: of course i do but i think i did nothing with the 'scale'

Comment: ahhhh sry? i came up with an idea

Comment: nah nothing I will upload two original files of them